# How to write a bash script that runs a linux command, and while it is running, runs another command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script that runs a command (e.g., command1), and **while** command1 is running, the script starts a second command (e.g., command2). And once command2 finishes, the script stops command1.

*What I tried*:
I tried `command1 & command2`. However, this does not enforce triggering command2 **AFTER** command1, which is in contrast with what I need. Using `command1 && command2` does not work either, as this would run command2 only after command1 is finished, which is not what I need.

Also, I don't know how to stop command1 once command2 is done.

Comment: `command1 & command2` does trigger `command2` after `command1`, but without any delay in between. If you need some sort of delay for `command1` to start up, you have what's known as a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), which is a fertile source of bugs and randon problems. At the very least, you should define what stage of its operation `command1` needs to get to before `command2` starts, and figure out how the script can test for that so it doesn't start `command2` too soon. Also, can `command2` be run too late?

Comment: See [ProcessManagement - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 8):

It looks like this is what you want:

```bash
command1 &      # put command1 in a background process
pid=$!          # store the id of the process running command1
command2        # execute command2
kill $pid       # kill command1 after command2 has finished
wait            # wait for (all) background command(s) to exit
```

Note: `kill`ing `command1` may abort it in places you don't like. Install a `trap` in `command1` to catch `SIGTERM` if you'd like a cleaner exit.

Comment: The script freezes like this. I need to run command1 and command2 in a while loop, so perhaps it does not work with ```wait```?

Comment: @azLe The example I gave should solve the problem as you've stated it in your question.   If you involve loops, it's important to know exactly _how_ and _where_ you loop in order to put the `wait` in the right place. You can update your question with details (and a [mre]) and ping me here again and I'll see if I can provide some solution.

Comment: @azle : You did not specify any looping in your question. If you can verify, that the answer by Ted Lyngmo works for the question you have actually asked (i.e. no loop context), please accept it and then ask a new question, where you demonstrate how you imbedded Ted's solution in a loop.

Comment: @azLe Since this question is still listed as "unanswered", can you please show a [mre] of how my suggestion makes the script freeze?